# How to print records from a MySQL table based on a field being equal to one of multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a table full of member records. There is a field called MB_COUNTRY, I want to display records when there MB_COUNTRY field = one of 6 values that I have chose.

**My Query:**

```
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM member ";
        $sql .= "WHERE MB_COUNTRY IN('103', '39', '149', '193', '194', '229')";
        $query1 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        ?>
```

**My table being displayed**

```
            <table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5" class="table table-hover table-striped">

            <tr>
                <td><strong>Company Name</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Website</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Phone</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Address</strong></td>
            </tr>

            <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) { ?>
            <tr> 
                <td><?php echo $row['MB_COMPANY'];?></td>
                <td><a href="http://<?php echo $row['MB_MOBILE'];?>"><?php echo $row['MB_MOBILE'];?></a></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['MB_PHONE'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['MB_ADDRESS1'];?>, <?php echo $row['MB_ADDRESS2'];?>, <?php echo $row['MB_TOWN'];?>, <?php echo $row['MB_COUNTY'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>

            </table>
```

**error**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE MB_COUNTRY = '103' OR MB_COUNTRY = '39' OR MB_COUNTRY = '149' OR MB_COUNTR' at line 1

As you can see I have tried using the OR operator however this produces an error (above). I simply want to display records that have a MB_COUNTRY value of: 
103' '39' '149' '193' '194' '229'

If anyone has a way of doing this I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: why you are spliting your query?

Comment: Left out a period... Looks like a typo to me -- voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

You have to concatenate your mysql query.
You also should use IN() for better performance and cleaner code.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM member ";
$sql .= "WHERE MB_COUNTRY IN('103', '39', '149', '193', '194', '229')";
```

Comment: I have tried this code and I do not think the query is running I want the query to run on page load. The error has gone however my table is still showing all the records in my database and not filtering them. Cheers anyway.

Comment: It does not make any sense, the query should work and filter the records accordingly. Please edit your original post and correct the issues with your code and update us what is happening with the new code(Please use the exact code the @Sofiane Sadi  provided)

Comment: Yes I ran it an it produced all the right results, for some reason the query is not filtering the table on page load. Thanks for the query though cause that definitely works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to concate the variable

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM member ";

    $sql .="WHERE MB_COUNTRY = '103' OR MB_COUNTRY =  ...";
```

Your $sql variable is reassigned to

```
 $sql ="WHERE MB_COUNTRY = '103' OR MB_COUNTRY =  ...";
```

And hence getting the error.

Comment: I have tried this and it has removed my error however my table is still showing all the records in my database and not filtering them. I want the query to run on page load is there a way to do this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: try the query in the DB directly and see what you get. You are using `or` so perhaps all the `or` is returning all the records ?

Comment: Yes I have just ran a new query -                                                             $sql = "SELECT * FROM member";                                                           $sql .= "WHERE MB_COUNTRY IN('103', '39', '149', '193', '194', '229')";                                                                                                       This has produced all the correct results however it is not running on page load, for some reason.